# cookies in laravel 5.2 - how to read

Tags: laravel, cookies, request, laravel-5

Before the Laravel 5.2 I had a small snippet to get a value stored in a cookie:

In my view:

```
    @if(!Cookie::has('colorTheme'))
        <?php $colortheme = 1; ?>
    @else
        <?php $colortheme = Cookie::get('colorTheme'); ?>
    @endif
```

Now these methods don't work. When I use this snippet in L5.2

```
$cookie_colorTheme = request()->cookie('colorTheme','1');
    @if(!isset($cookie_colorTheme)) 
        <?php $cookie_colorTheme = '1'; ?>
    @endif
    <link rel="stylesheet" class='a' id='colortheme' href="{{asset('css/colortheme_'.$cookie_colorTheme.'.css')}}">
```

It also doesn't work, as the cookie is not in request - it is already stored on the user's computer.

#### My questions:

- how can I read a cookie in Laravel 5.2
- If the cookie is not found, how can I set a default value

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks ok, so maybe cookies are just empty. Try `dd($_COOKIE)` or something similar to understand what's going on.

To set default value, you can do this:

```
{{ $value = $request->cookie('name') ? $request->cookie('name') : 'default value' }}
```

or you can try to do [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#displaying-data) in a Blade template:

```
{{ $request->cookie('name') or 'default value' }}
```

Comment: I have ended up with this `<link rel="stylesheet" class='a' id='colortheme' href="{{asset('css/colortheme_'.request()->cookie('colorTheme','1').'.css')}}">`